# How to make page flip effect in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, animation, page-flipping

All the info i found about page fliping is just source code that i'm having trouble implementing to my code.
[this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13202/A-Page-Turn-Effect-Using-C)

kinda explains the logic behind page fliping but the code is for windows form and not WPF.
i dunno how to approach it because as i understood bitmaps are not used the same in WPF.

anyone has a good tutorial or could give me some pointers?
What im trying to do is i have an image that fills entire screen and i want to flip it to to next image ( like a book) that will also take the entire screen.
(Not 2 images on a screen)

Help?

To anybody that suggests using C++ or DirectX, I'm not interesting in learning those skills.  Only C# code please.

Comment: Have you tried searching for other tutorials using keywords from that article and appending "WPF" to the search?

Comment: Yes i have... wouldn't post before googling the hell out of it.

Comment: I'm surprised nothing turned up, that's all. I must be getting cynical (I see too many questions where basic research hasn't been done). Though I've just turned up this - http://wpfbookcontrol.codeplex.com/. It's a bit old but should give you a start.

Comment: Ya i found that. not very helping i'm having trouble implementing it to my case because having trouble to understand how page fliping works. that's why i asked this question might someone explain it somehow

Comment: It would be worth posting the code you're having difficulty with. It'll stop people posting links to stuff you've already seen :)

Comment: That's true but i'm completly lost lol i have nothing. i'm reading the code of all those examples and can't figure out how i can implement it without just copying-pasting ( tried that, all hell broke loose)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WPF bag o'tricks has a page flip sample with code.

The github source
https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot

Specifically, look at the TransitionPresenter sample in the demo project where there are multiple transitions defined, one being page flipping.

Comment: @eric.itzhak : Sorry about that. Ive removed the bad link. The github link is working though.